Login to Webpage with Password without Selenium
I run a range of scripts for pulling financial information for investments I hold. One of these is with a company called Raiz. This is the only investment I have which I require to login for and therefore I have been using Selenium / Chromium for this on a Raspberry Pi 4 (which also runs my home automation and Jellyfin server. Recently this one script has not been successfully running most of the time.
Thinking if I can change to pulling this data via using the requests library or similar which utilises less resources I may have more luck (as the issue appears to occur when the load on server is higher but that can be anytime and I need these scripts to ideally run in the afternoon / early evening.
I have tried to adapt my other code I use and also few examples from online but run into various errors such as 405 and others. Hoping someone may be able to have a quick look and point me in the right direction
Website is https://app.raizinvest.com.au/login
Have been trying via Post (as this seems to be correct from what I can see from developer console with a payload of
payload = {
'email': 'f......@outlook.com.au',
'password': 'w......'
}
Any pointers or if there is some way to tell if it is even possible. Have read that allow_redirects=True can help with the 405 but have added that to the post request and doesn't seem to have helped. Have put the start code I have below. Will then need to work out the extraction once it logs in separately but this is the first step
import requests 
payload = {
    'email': 'f.....@outlook.com.au',
    'password': 'w.........'
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.75 Safari/537.36'
}

loginurl = "https://app.raizinvest.com.au"
with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.get(loginurl)
    print (p.text)
    p = s.post(loginurl, headers=headers, data=payload, allow_redirects=True)
    print (p.text)

import requests 
payload = {
    'email': 'f.......@outlook.com.au',
    'password': 'w........'
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.75 Safari/537.36'
}

loginurl = "https://app.raizinvest.com.au"
with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post(loginurl, headers=headers, data=payload, allow_redirects=True)
    print (p.text)


Ideally expecting to see some details indicating it had successfully logged in. I get the same output regardless of whether I have valid or garbled login details so I therefore know it basically isn't getting anywhere either way. I realise there is limited assistance that can be provided due to the nature of not providing valid credentials but hopefully just from the login page someone can steer me where I need to look or options to explore

sounds like they have really effective anti-bot mechanism.  probably checking time between keystrokes. see if they expose the data by API.
